# Copying files from sharepoint to google cloud sotrage based on event trigger

Tags: google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface, cron-task, google-cloud-storage

i need to copy files from a sharepoint to GCS automatically: everytime there is a new file in the sharepoint,it should be copied automatically  to GCS? any hint please ?

Comment: Were you able to achieve this? Looking for a similar solution.

Comment: I'm trying to use https://docs.cloudquery.io/integrations/sharepoint, but for now I was just able to export a CSV file to my GCS with the file names from the sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a definitive answer, but, maybe we could build it up togetter

Install CloudQuery

```
curl -L https://github.com/cloudquery/cloudquery/releases/download/cli-v5.1.2/cloudquery_linux_amd64 -o cloudquery
chmod a+x cloudquery
```

Create the source file `sharepoint.yml`

```
kind: source
spec:
  name: "sharepoint"
  registry: "github"
  path: "koltyakov/sharepoint"
  version: "v2.1.0" # provide the latest version
  destinations: ["gcs"] # the list of used destinations
  tables: ["*"] # required field, a list of tables to sync
  spec:
    auth:
      strategy: "ondemand"
      creds:
        siteUrl: "https://yoursubdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite"
    lists:
      Shared Documents:
        select:
          - FileLeafRef
          - FileRef
          - FileDirRef
          - File/Length
        expand:
          - File
        alias: "document"
```

And then the Destination file

```
kind: destination
spec:
  name: "gcs"
  path: "cloudquery/gcs"
  registry: "cloudquery"
  version: "v3.4.17"
  spec:
    bucket: "your-bucket"
    path: "path/to/dest/"
    format: "csv" # options: parquet, json, csv
```

You will need to connect to your GCS with gloud auth, so your credentials will be available on your terminal

Run this
`cloudquery sync sharepoint.yml gcs.yml`

You will be prompted a web browser to put your SharePoint Credentials

With this code, you will have 1 or more CSV files on your GCS listing all the files from Sharepoint

From now, it was all I could do, but I think I'm on the right path